# How to deploy a backend server with Hostinger

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, backend, hosting

Hi I have created a **react js** project with a **node js** backend server. Now I want to deploy my site on the web but I don't find how to deploy the backend. I also have a hostinger plan. Can you explain me how to do that?

This is how my project looks like:

[image]

in the react part I make API requests to the server.

Comment: Which plan You have now?

Comment: @AjayRaja it's the premium web hosting I think

Comment: You need to have VPS Plan for nodejs hosting

Comment: @AjayRaja oh ok should I take the hostinger one?

Comment: My recommended approach is to use Netlify.You can use Hostinger Domain with Netlify If You want. Disclaimer: I am not promoting any Products in Stackoverflow.com